# Differences between BlockingCollection and TaskScheduler

Tags: c#

I was seeking to parallelize some work on my project and I used Parallel.ForEach first and it worked good enough for the mean time, then the lead dev came up and said that he didn't really like this and wanted to change that.

Then I decided to do a TaskScheduler along a TaskFactory to batch the work, work flawless and fast, again he didn't like it and find it overkill and old, he said I should use BlockingCollection with Consumer/Producer pattern, he started to implement this and I don't see the advantage over a TaskScheduler. Maybe for maintenance problems, or to keep the complexity to something acceptable, I don't know.

Here some context, the work is transforming data from memory, the data do not need to have a synchronization context, each operations can be taken separately, no IO bounds and all the code is thread-safe.

So, what the differences between the BlockingCollection and TaskScheduler for a parallel work ?

Comment: They have nothing in common. `BlockingCollection` is a specific type of collection. TaskScheduler is the class that controls how tasks are mapped to threads for execution. For data parallelism you don't really need *either*. You'll have to explain your actual problem

Comment: `he didn't really like this` what was this? Why? Parallel.ForEach works *very* well for data parallelism - a scenario where a lot of data has to be partitioned and processed by independent workers. The less synchronization between workers, the faster the performance is. By default, all cores are used. You can't get faster than that *provided there's no need for synchronization between the workers*

Comment: Maybe your work is `IO bound` and async which means `Parallel.ForEach` is not suitable. anyway, you need more information, as this question is fairly unanswerable in its current state

Comment: If on the other hand the workers modify common state all the time, if they increment global values etc, you waste time waiting for access to that common resource. So the solution is to write your code so there's minimal need for sync

Comment: BTW `Parallel.ForEach` already implements pub/sub. The Pub is the input enumerable, the sub are the workers. It works perfectly for **data** parallelism. Not async, not concurrent operations. Parallelism!=Async!=Concurrent.

Comment: What is the actual problem? This question can't be answered as is. What is the actual scenario? Parallel processing of lots of local data? Concurrent IO? Async calls to remote services? A processing pipeline? Those are *very* different scenarios, requiring different strategies, different designs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just no problems, just wanna know how a BlockingCollection with Consumer/Producer pattern could achieve parallel work as good as Parallel.ForEach or TaskScheduling.

Comment: @MichaelRandall No IO operations, just memory data operations.

Comment: That question is meaningless. What are you *actually* trying to do? What is the *actual* problem? And why do you think that `Parallel.ForEach` isn't good enough, or that a blocking collection *adding* overhead could be better? It's far more likely that the code is blocking due to synchronization.

Comment: Those aren't idle questions. Without those answers it's impossible to say what's wrong, or what could be done better. Using a `BlockingCollection` isn't an answer to data parallelism problems

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What I am trying to do is transforming data from memory, no data synchronization, each operations can be taken separately, all the class are thread-safe. Here I want to know why he want to use BlockingCollection for parallel work. He didn't want to use Parallel.ForEach because he can't know the behavior behind this when running. (Though I don't see why because I had any problems using this, just a list of task with extra steps)

Comment: @Maillful how can anyone say when there's no information? `he can't know the behavior behind this when running.` he can read the source code, it's open source. Or he can read the docs - [Data Parallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/data-parallelism-task-parallel-library), [Patterns for Parallel Programming: Understanding and Applying Parallel Patterns with the .NET Framework 4](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=19222)

Comment: Also [Custom Partitioners for LINQ and TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl). That explains the types of partitioning (static vs dynamic), their inherent *batching* and load balancing behavior, how to create custom partitioners if needed, or  how to configure the built-in partitioners

Comment: Also [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) - the best performance gain you can get depends on the part of the work that *can't* be parallelized. Which explains why BlockingCollection or any kind of sync is bad.

Comment: Also using a custom taskscheduler could be a problem - there's no point in using more threads than cores, and *some core* has to run the TaskScheduler code too, which means it's not processing data.

Comment: Another problem  - data locality. It's far faster to read consecutive RAM addresses, and data in the Cache is far faster than data in RAM. Batched data is consecutive. For small amounts of data, using a single core with a List<T> or T[] buffer could be faster than parallel processing due to RAM transfer costs. That's why PLINQ/Parallel batches the data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I gave the users the choice to process their data either in parallel or sequential, when the data set is small, they use the sequential one and vice versa for big data set. And for the taskscheduler, I limit the number of cores/threads for the operations and left some space for system and other thing to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, what the differences between the BlockingCollection and TaskScheduler for a parallel work ?

As the comments said, they are as different as night and oranges. `BlockingCollection<T>` ist the collection you find in the Namespace `System.Collections.Concurrent`. Wich consists basically of everything from `System.Collections.Generic` they could fully protect from race conditions via the use of [lock statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) in every sensible place.

If you got a colletion you want outside this, they could not proof the collection fully against Race Conditions from the inside. Only the code using those collections can avoid race conditions (a likely reason why Array and `List<T>` do not have a concurrent counterpart).

> he didn't really like this
>
> again he didn't like it and find it overkill and old, he said I should use BlockingCollection with Consumer/Producer pattern

Then the difference does not realy mater either way. The choice is out of your hand.

There are either requirements elsewhere you do not (yet) know. Or "old dogs do not learn new tricks" applies.

Comment: That's more like [Not Invented Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here). TPL is 10 years old already

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not that much if the dog is over 20 human years.^^ Plus option A still does exist. If the dog is >10 years old, I shudder to think how old the code is.